# Predictions made by neural network are incorrect

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to build a neural network from scratch to do image recognition on the minst database but the code not only produces incorrect answer it seems way off .

I have tried to look at weights and biases in intermediate step but since there is no way to know what weights and biases should be i have no idea how to solve it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
(xtrain,ytrain),(xtest,ytest)=tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
import numpy as np
import random
flatlist1=[x.flatten() for x in xtrain]
flatlist2=[x.flatten() for x in xtest]
traininp=[]
testinp=[]
for i in range(len(ytrain)):
    traininp.append([flatlist1[i],ytrain[i]])
for i in range(len(ytest)):
    testinp.append([flatlist1[i],ytest[i]])
def sigmoid(x):
        return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-x))
def sigmoid_der(x):
        return sigmoid(x)*(1-sigmoid(x))

def relu(x):
        return max(0,x)
def relu_der(x):
        if x>0:
                return 1
        else:
                return 0

class NeuralNetwork(object):

    def __init__(self,traininp,layers):
        #Add a list layer provideing no of nodes in each layer
        #add training input as array of pixel grayscale values and output in a list
        self.num_layers = len(layers)
        self.layers = layers.insert(0,len(traininp[0][0]))
        self.weights=[]
        self.biases = [((np.random.randn(y, 1)).flatten()).tolist() for y in layers[1:]]
        for y in range(1,len(layers[1:])+1):
            weight=[]
            for x in range(layers[y]):
                weight.append(((np.random.randn(layers[y-1],1)).flatten()).tolist() )
            self.weights.append(weight)

        self.nweights=[]
        self.nbiases=[]
        for i in range(len(self.weights)):
            w=[]
            for j in self.weights[i]:
                w.append([0]*len(j))
            self.nweights.append(w)
        for i in self.biases:
            self.nbiases.append([0]*len(i))
            x=0
        for i in range(10):
            for k in range(20):
                predictions=self.feedforward(traininp[x][0],layers)
                dbiases,dweights=self.Backprop(traininp[x][1],predictions)
                self.nbiases=self.addbiases(self.nbiases,dbiases)
                self.nweights=self.addweights(self.nweights,dweights)
                x+=1
            self.updateb(self.biases,self.nbiases,0.1,20)
            self.updatew(self.weights,self.nweights,0.1,20)
        for i in range(190,210):
            predictions=self.feedforward(traininp[i][0],layers)
            print(predictions[-1],predictions[-1].index(max(predictions[-1])),traininp[i][1])

    def calculate(self,inp,weights,bias):
        wsum=0.0
        for x,y in zip(weights,inp):
            wsum+=x*y
        return (wsum+bias)

    def feedforward(self,traininp,layers):
        firstz=[self.calculate(traininp,self.weights[0][i],self.biases[0][i]) for i in range(layers[1])]
        firstlayer=[sigmoid(i) for i in firstz]
        outputlayers=[]
        outputlayers.append((traininp).tolist())
        self.zs=[]
        self.zs.append(firstz)
        outputlayers.append(firstlayer)
        for x in range(1,len(layers[1:])):
            z=[]
            k=[]
            for i in range(layers[x+1]):
                z.append(self.calculate(outputlayers[x-1],self.weights[x][i],self.biases[x][i]))
                k.append(sigmoid(z[i]))
            self.zs.append(z)
            outputlayers.append(k)
        return(outputlayers)

    def Backprop(self,traininp,predictions):
        dweights=[]
        dbiases=[]
        dnodes=[]
        dweights=self.nweights.copy()
        dbiases=self.nbiases.copy()
        y=[0]*len(predictions[-1])
        y[traininp]=1
        for i in predictions:
            dnodes.append([0]*len(i))
        for i in range(len(y)):
            dbiases[-1][i]=sigmoid_der(self.zs[-1][i])*self.cost(predictions[-1][i],y[i])
            for j in range(len(predictions[-2])):
                dweights[-1][i][j]=predictions[-2][j]*sigmoid_der(self.zs[-1][i])*self.cost(predictions[-1][i],y[i])
            dweights[-1][i][j]/=j
            for j in range(len(self.weights[-1])):
                for k in range(len(self.weights[-1][j])):
                    dnodes[-1][i]=self.weights[-1][j][k]*sigmoid_der(self.zs[-1][i])*self.cost(predictions[-1][i],y[i])
                dnodes[-1][i]/=k
        for k in range(2,self.num_layers+1):
            for i in range(len(predictions[-k])):
                dbiases[-k][i]=sigmoid_der(self.zs[-k][i])*self.cost(predictions[-k][i],dnodes[-k][i])
                for j in range(len(self.weights[-k])):
                    for l in range(len(self.weights[-k][j])):
                        dnodes[-k][i]=self.weights[-k][j][l]*sigmoid_der(self.zs[-k][i])*self.cost(predictions[-k][i],dnodes[-k][i])
                    dnodes[-k][i]/=l
                for j in range(len(predictions[-k-1])):
                    dweights[-k][i][j]=predictions[-k-1][j]*sigmoid_der(self.zs[-k][i])*self.cost(predictions[-k][i],dnodes[-k][i])
                dweights[-k][i][j]/=j
        return (dbiases,dweights)        

    def cost(self,output,y):
        return (2*(output-y))

    def addbiases(self,list1,list2):
        listo=[]
        for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
            listt=[]
            for k,l in zip(i,j):
                listt.append(k+l)
            listo.append(listt)
        return listo

    def addweights(self,list1,list2):
        listo=[]
        for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
            lists=[]
            for k,l in zip(i,j):
                listt=[]
                for p,q in zip(k,l):
                    listt.append(p+q)
                lists.append(listt)
            listo.append(lists)
        return listo

    def updatew(self,list1,list2,eta,bsize):
        listo=[]
        for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
            lists=[]
            for k,l in zip(i,j):
                listt=[]
                for p,q in zip(k,l):
                    listt.append(p-(eta/bsize)*q)
                lists.append(listt)
            listo.append(lists)
        return listo

    def updateb(self,list1,list2,eta,bsize):
        listo=[]
        for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
            listt=[]
            for k,l in zip(i,j):
                listt.append(k-(eta/bsize)*l)
            listo.append(listt)
        return listo


n1=NeuralNetwork(traininp[0:210],[5,5,10])
```

I at least want it to work like a neural network even if it doesn't have high accuracy or even if it works at a slow speed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Give us the input and a driver program, as well as your output and traces.  If you don't know what to look for, perhaps one of us will know.

Comment: @Amitya I know where you are right now. I've been where you are 6 months ago. I respect your enthusiasm. See if this link helps you. https://github.com/Horopter/NeuralNetworks-2018/tree/master/Chapter%201%20:%20Learning%20the%20Algorithm

Comment: @Prune I have added the input I have used. Now the given program should execute on any system with python 3 and appropriate libraries like tensorflow installed.also this program trains on 200 input and checks 20 data sample 10 previously seen and 10 new .I have limited the train data to 200 because the program is slow .If any other modifications or information is required feel free to comment

Comment: Thanks; looks much better.  Now I find that I have to upgrade my modules -- I have Python3.7, but haven't upgraded the TF world since 3.4.  This might take my interstices for a couple of days, uninstalling and reinstalling.  BTW, the closure vote and down-vote are not mine.